# from Console to Web-App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What would be a 'non-console application' representation of the following code.

```
    class Sword 
    {
        public void Hit(string target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chopped {0} clean in half", target);
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what this code would look like in a C# ASP.NET MVC project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Sword 
{
    public string Hit(string target)
    {
        return string.Format("Chopped {0} clean in half", target);
    }
}
```

and then you could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var sword = new Sword();
        return View((object)sword.Hit("foo"));
    }
}
```

and a corresponding view:

```
@model string
<div>@Model</div>
```

I have strictly no idea why your question is tagged with Ninject, but if you want to use Ninject in an ASP.NET MVC application you may install the `Ninject.MVC3` NuGet package and go through some tutorials such as [this one](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application) for example.

Comment: I mentioned ninject because it was copied from [their page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand). And removing it as it obviously annoys you (and because your right (I concede)).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `SwordController` with the action `Hit`:

```
public class SwordController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Hit(string target)
    {
        return Content(string.Format("Chopped {0} in half", target));
    }
}
```

If you access the page using this URL: `http://[domain]/Sword/Hit?target=watermelon` you'll see this string in your Web browser: `Chopped watermelon in half`.

Answer (score 1):

On an Web app, your "Console" is your HTTP Response; therefore, that piece of code on a web app, would look like this:

```
class Sword 
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Chopped {0} clean in half", target));
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is incorrect. Throws the following error: Since 'Samurai.Models.Sword.Hit(string)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.net you would do something like this

```
Response.Write(string.format("Chopped {0} clean in half", target);
```

Comment: This one is incorrect. Throws the following error: Since 'Samurai.Models.Sword.Hit(string)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression